Azure function, binding name and blob client
I have a Java azure function that has a blob trigger binding name and I process the file and finally write the file to a different location using block client.
The following behavior is observed occasionally. A blob by the input file name is created in the location where the output file is created using blob client.
Does this behavior have to do with binding name?
public void run(@BlobTrigger( name = "file", path = "container/{name}", dataType = "binary") byte[] fileCont, 
@bindingName("name") String name,
final ExecutionContext context) { } 


Can you share your code in the question?

public void run(@BlobTrigger( name = "file", path = "container/{name}", dataType = "binary") byte[]  fileCont, @bindingName("name") String name, final ExecutionContext context) {
}

Can you able to run the blob trigger function code which you have shared above?

@Ramar kindly edit your question to update your code in the question instead of comment section

The BlobTrigger uses the {name} placeholder to get the blob's name, and @BindingName("name") stores it in the name variable for use, like setting the output file path.
To prevent overwriting, change the output blob name by modifying the input file's name, avoiding conflicts.
BlobTriggerJava.java :
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.*;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.*;
import com.azure.storage.blob.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

public class BlobTriggerJava {
    @FunctionName("BlobTriggerJava")
    @StorageAccount("AZURE_STORAGE")
    public void run(
            @BlobTrigger(name = "file", path = "kamcontainer/{name}", dataType = "binary") byte[] fileCont,
            @BindingName("name") String name,
            final ExecutionContext context
    ) {
        context.getLogger().info("Processing blob. Name: " + name + ", Size: " + fileCont.length + " bytes.");
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                .connectionString(System.getenv("AZURE_STORAGE")) 
                .buildClient();
        String outputBlobPath = "outputblob/demokam-" + name; 
        BlobClient blobClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("outputblob")
                .getBlobClient("demokam-" + name);
        byte[] data = fileCont; 
        blobClient.upload(new ByteArrayInputStream(data), data.length, true);
        context.getLogger().info("Content successfully copied to " + outputBlobPath);
    }
}

local.setting.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<Storeconnecstring>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java",
    "AZURE_STORAGE": "<Storeconnecstring>"
  }
}

pom.xml :
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
        <version>12.10.0</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.32</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
         <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
         <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
         <version>2.23.4</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Output :
The following blob trigger function ran successfully as shown below.

Input Container blob data :

Output Container blob data :

